# Efficiently mutate a vector while also iterating over the same vector

Tags: rust

I have a vector of structs, and I'm comparing every element in the vector against every other element, and in certain cases mutating the current element.

My issue is that you can't have both a mutable and immutable borrow happening at the same time, but I'm not sure how to reframe my problem to get around this without cloning either the current element or the entire vector, which seems like a waste since I'm only ever mutating the current element, and it doesn't need to be compared to itself (I skip that case).

I'm sure there's an idiomatic way to do this in Rust.

```
struct MyStruct {
    a: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![MyStruct { a: 1 }, MyStruct { a: 2 }, MyStruct { a: 3 }];

    for elem in v.iter_mut() {
        for other_elem in v.iter() {
            if other_elem.a > elem.a {
                elem.a += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help to see how you're *currently* trying to structure your code.  This seems eminently doable.

Comment: I added an example. I stumbled up [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41285979/943814) which makes me think split_at_mut or something similar might be the solution.

Comment: You are basically trying to visit all pairs of a slice. Strangely, I find no crate to do this.

Comment: @Boiethios [`itertools::iproduct`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.7/itertools/macro.iproduct.html) would do that... without solving the mutability issue, of course.

Comment: @kazemakase That's the whole point ;)

Comment: @kazemakase FYI, I did an iterator for this: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1702560 Maybe I will create a create for tools like that.

Comment: @Boiethios nice. I thought of doing something similar.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simplest way is to just use indices, which don't involve any long-lived borrows:

```
for i in 0..v.len() {
    for j in 0..v.len() {
        if i == j { continue; }
        if v[j].a > v[i].a {
            v[i].a += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

If you really, *really* want to use iterators, you can do it by dividing up the `Vec` into disjoint slices:

```
fn process(elem: &mut MyStruct, other: &MyStruct) {
    if other.a > elem.a {
        elem.a += 1;
    }
}

for i in 0..v.len() {
    let (left, mid_right) = v.split_at_mut(i);
    let (mid, right) = mid_right.split_at_mut(1);
    let elem = &mut mid[0];

    for other in left {
        process(elem, other);
    }
    for other in right {
        process(elem, other);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Using indices seems obvious in retrospect.

Comment: Anything that can change the size of the vector could invalidate references, so I can understand why the vector container itself couldn't be mutated while iterating, but what is Rust trying to save me from by preventing me from mutating the elements?

Comment: @JosephGarvin you can mutate the elements, but you can't have a shared reference at the same time as a mutable reference. Consider if your vector (v1) contains vectors (v2), and you are iterating over v1 with both iter() and iter_mut() at the same time. You will have a &mut and & of v2. Now consider that through the & you get the 1st element of v2, then through &mut you resize the vec to 0. That & to the first element now points to invalid memory.

Answer (score -1):

If you can modify type type of v, and the elements of v are `Copy`, you can wrap `MyStruct` in `Cell`.

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)] 
struct MyStruct {
    a: i32,
}

fn main() {
    use std::cell::Cell;
    let v = vec![
        Cell::new(MyStruct { a: 1 }),
        Cell::new(MyStruct { a: 2 }),
        Cell::new(MyStruct { a: 3 }),
    ];

    for elem in v.iter() {
        for other_elem in v.iter() {
            let mut e = elem.get();
            if other_elem.get().a > e.a {
                e.a += 1;
                elem.set(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If instead you're passed a &mut to a slice (or &mut that can be converted into a slice), use `Cell::from_mut` and `Cell::as_slice_of_cells` and use the same trick as above (assuming the elements of the slice are `Copy`).