# Performing operations on immutable borrow when iterating using mutable iterator

Tags: rust, ownership

Here is a simple artificial example to illustrate the problem:

```
fn sum_slice(v: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    v.iter().sum()
}

fn sum_previous(v: &mut [i32]) {
    for (i, val) in v.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        *val = sum_slice(&v[0..i]);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
    sum_previous(&mut v);
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Ideally the intention is that `sum_previous` will take the slice provided and replace each element with the sum of previous ones.

But this is generating the error:

```
    error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*v` as immutable because it is also borrowed as 
    mutable

    --> src/main.rs:7:27
      |
    6 |     for (i, val) in v.iter_mut().enumerate() {
      |                     ------------------------
      |                     |
      |                     mutable borrow occurs here
      |                     mutable borrow later used here
    7 |         *val = sum_slice(&v[0..i]);
      |                           ^ immutable borrow occurs here
```

[Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=06680974a7b52d45a4600ce74cd976ba)

I understand the problem that Rust is restricting us to have exactly one mutable reference and no immutable at the same time. I can also come with different solutions such as using another vector to store the results, but the question is not how to work around it but what is the acceptable pattern here?

FWIW the original problem is implementation of a cellular automaton, where a grid to be processed and each cell to be updated based on its neighbours. In that case the grid is borrowed mutably, while the function to calculate the update is expecting an immutable reference.

Comment: Also [Efficiently mutate a vector while also iterating over the same vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143770/efficiently-mutate-a-vector-while-also-iterating-over-the-same-vector), which also suggests using indices. You're using them already for `&v[0..i]`; there's not really any reason to prefer `*val` over `v[i]`. I actually think using indices consistently is more readable than mixing indexing with iteration.

Comment: @trentcl Thank you, this is a good duplicate - reflecting exactly my initial problem

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut):

```rust
fn sum_previous(v: &mut [i32]) {
    for i in 1..v.len() {
        let (head, tail) = v.split_at_mut(i);
        tail[0] = sum_slice(head);
    }
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d312550ba5461cf83dc9763fcd0773c7))

Comment: Thank you, that is an interesting find for me and is providing kind of a solution to the artificial example, but I am not sure how it solves the general problem. Say we are working not with slices but with some `struct` where one method will take `&mut self` and will try to execute another method taking non-mutable `&self`

Comment: @EugeneSh. That isn't a problem as you having `&mut` on the struct also allows you to call methods and functions requiring immutable references to it ([example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aae8b7a3ff23ec4361a0c90d7aafff0e)). The issue only really happens when dealing with iterators, and there's always a way around it.

Comment: @EugeneSh.I don't think there is a "general problem" but many different ones... they often look similar but in the end turn out to have different solutions. In the example of a &mut method calling another: you can borrow your "&mut self" onwards as "&self" so there's no issue -- the problem only exists if you need both references at the same time.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen May I show you the initial problem? It does look like I need both references in the same time.. It's [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b986871883167404bd2a1f719866724e). If you think the example in my question is not representative I might need to edit it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. This is a variation of Conway's game of life - are you sure you are supposed to modify the weights in-situ? As in, are you sure that a neighbor being updated should trigger an update on the **immediate** moment using a partially-updated grid? I don't think that's the case; I don't know a single cellular automaton that works like this.

Comment: I [found your cellular automaton](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Cellular_Automata_Method_for_Generating_Random_Cave-Like_Levels). It is not how you think it is. The update function works on the **prior iteration**, and therefore is a two-step process when you compute the new state based on the old separately, and then swap them.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld You have found the right one. As you can see the calculation is performed on the "current" value and is attempted to get assigned to "next". Just to emphasize - it's not that I must make it work at all costs. I am just trying to learn and took this little project as something that can help practice many different concepts, so you might find some "solutions" suboptimal.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That is not what you are implementing. You're mixing the "current" and "next" steps because you're doing modifications in-place. I can't write an answer with this as that is not the answer to your question, so consider this case. A "current" cell has 4 neighbors. One of the other neighbors got turned in-situ into a wall. This "current" cell therefore would turn into 5 and into a wall in your code, whereas it doesn't and shouldn't.

Comment: Almost every cellular automaton requires a two step process and 2*N memory allocations, where N is the size of your grid. One for the "current" state, one for the "next" step, and every iteration you trampoline between the two.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld The calculation is performed before the swap occurs (that part is not even there yet). I'll see how I can come up with better [mcve], but probably later..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200424/discussion-between-sebastien-renauld-and-eugene-sh).