# Efficiently check each item in a vec against other and also mutate

Tags: rust

How can I efficiently loop through a Vec, compare each item against each other and also mutate if needed? Right now I have:

```
let s_len = s.len();
for i in 0..s_len - 1 {
     for j in i + 1..s_len { 
        // Perform a lot of checks and assignments, eg s[i].x = s[j].y or s[j].z = s[i].x
   }
}
```

However, I read that its more efficient to do like:

```
if let Some(a) = s.get_mut(i) {
    ...
}
```

Obviously I can't do that on both due to borrow checker. Any ideas on how to speed up this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently mutate a vector while also iterating over the same vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143770/efficiently-mutate-a-vector-while-also-iterating-over-the-same-vector)

Answer (score 2):

`get_mut` isn't any faster than indexing - it just won't panic and will instead give you an option.

The indexing solution you're using is basically as performant as you can get. You will get a performance hit from Rust performing bounds checking, but this shouldn't be a major factor. The indexes allow you to mutate without borrowing issues.

You may be able to avoid the bounds checking by using iterators and splitting the vector as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143770/efficiently-mutate-a-vector-while-also-iterating-over-the-same-vector). This is a bit more complex than just the indexing though but arguably also somewhat safer and possibly even better performing because you avoid the bounds check.