# It is possible to mutate the values of a for loop using pointers

Tags: rust

I am traversing a vector using a for loop, and using pointers to try to change the value of a vector if it is even.

I tried to use pointers but I don't know if it is being implemented correctly

Code:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let v = Rc::new(RefCell::new(vec![1,2,3]));
    
    println!("{:?}",v.borrow());
    
    for (e,i) in v.borrow().iter().enumerate() {
        if i%2 == 0{
            v.borrow_mut()[e] = i*2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need `Rc` and `RefCell` specifically, or was that just something you tried?

Comment: it was something I tried

Comment: Okay, then this should answer your question: [Efficiently mutate a vector while also iterating over the same vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143770/efficiently-mutate-a-vector-while-also-iterating-over-the-same-vector)

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed,yes, but it's possible make it with pointer as in  example

Comment: [Here is an example of applying the duplicate answer to your use case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c8a10337865945011c8af712a3bf2002)

Comment: You don't need `RefCell` or indices for this. Just [iterate over `&mut v`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d3aa70387efe67e1d658c156d2ff2526).